# Finding Most Efficient Block Size for Cache Blocking (Tiling) Optimization

Tags: caching, optimization

When performing an experiment to determine the effectiveness of the cache blocking optimization technique (4kB of level 1 cache with 16 sets, 4-way associativity, and a block size of 64 bytes) against a matrix multiplication function with two 256x256 input matrices, I determined the optimal block size was 16. Is the optimal block size of this optimization directly associated with the number of sets in every case? For example, in another configuration (fully associative 64 kB of level 1 cache with a block size of 64 bytes), would the optimal block size be 1 (therefore, resulting in no optimization using this technique)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the number of sets that are available and the optimal block size for the blocking algorithm are not related. For this particular case, blocking with a block size of half of the matrix size (128) would be the optimal size when ignoring all other factors.